# Compare data of two offline Windows servers (via file hash?)

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2016

I have two Windows servers (2016) in two different places, both with about 8TB of data. They both should have the identical files and file structure, but it's possible that things got changed between them. I want to identify files that either don't match or are present on one server but not the other.

My theory is that this should be possible through some looping of Powershell's [Get-FileHash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-6), where I run it on one server, export the data to a file, then move that file to the second server and somehow compare it - but I'm not enough of a Powershell guru to do it myself, unfortunately.

There may also be a utility that can do this, if anyone knows of one - the main sticking point is that I can't use a program that simply compares both directories, because the two servers are not connected to the same network (or the internet) at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [rhash](http://rhash.sourceforge.net/).  It is small and straightforward to use and should be perfect for your scenario.

It generates a text file containing a list of files in the target directory (including subdirectories) and their hashes.  You can then compare the two text files (using, e.g., windiff) to identify any discrepancies.

The command line to use would look something like this:

```
cd /d c:\directory\to\be\hashed
rhash --sha512 -r -o e:\output.txt .
```

(You want to make the hashing operation relative to the current directory so that the output file contains relative paths rather than absolute paths.  Absolute paths would make it difficult to compare the two output files.)

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty similar to what I had in mind - the next question is, if I do this on the two computers, does rhash have an automated way of comparing the two outputs? Or would I just use some kind of text-based comparison utility?

Comment: hows about a vpn?

Comment: No, rhash just generates the hashes.  You need a text comparison utility to check that the hashes match.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a DFS replication between the two servers. That would make sure each server serve the same file set, and that would allow you to setup sync schedule in case it's a low bandwitdh site.

Read more there please; [DFS Replication overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/dfsr-overview)

Comment: Do you have any information about doing this across servers that are not connected?

Comment: @Jake Oh, no. A simple robocopy with HDD then would be a better option

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying to just copy the data to a hard drive from server A, then copy it from the hard drive onto server B? I know robocopy can do verification to prevent unnecessary copies when the files are identical - but my goal is to not have to create a third copy of the files, and instead just check their "status" via hash comparison

Comment: @Jake If they are not interconnected, they are independant. Whats your goal ? as if the file are not consistant, what would you do ? bring a copy anyway to replace the file ?

Comment: Yes - if an individual file is not consistent, I'll figure out a way to make it consistent, perhaps by bringing a hard drive containing only the inconsistent files. Alternatively, if the difference is a filename or something, I can rename the file without any transfers. It's perfectly possible to move the 8TB of data from one place to another, but given that it's potentially sensitive data, I'd prefer another way if possible